# How can you pass a bound variable to an ng-click function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple delete button that will accept a string or number but won't accept an ng-model variable ( not sure if that's the correct terminology ).

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete('{{submission.id}}')">delete</button>
```

Which generates:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete('503a9742d6df30dd77000001')">delete</button>
```

However, nothing happens when I click. If I hard code a variable then it works just fine. I assume I'm just not doing things the "Angular" way, but I'm not sure what that way is :)

Here's my controller code:

```
$scope.delete = function ( id ) {
    alert( 'delete ' + id );
}
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You don't need to use curly brackets (`{{}}`) in the `ng-click`, try this:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(submission.id)">delete</button>
```

Comment: how would I then pass submission.id through a function? From what I understand function(submission.id) {} would not not work in my controller because a function cannot except a period

Comment: * Clarification * ::  You don't need to use curly braces when passing angular values to the attributes, but you will still need them in the internal HTML markup.  Example: <button ng-click="delete(submission.id)">{{submission.displayValue}}</button>

Comment: I was wondering why it was passing brackets to function instead of variable value when doing this: `<button data-ng-click="toggleDetails('v_{{ $index }}')">Details</button>`  Your answer really helped: `<button  data-ng-click="toggleDetails('v_' + $index)">Details</button>`  Funny thing is, the wrong way looked like it was properly rendering in the developer tools window.

Answer (score 1):

The **[`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)** directive binds an **expression**. It executes Angular code directly (as [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), [`ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange), etc.) without the need of `{{ }}`.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.submission = { id: 100 };

    $scope.delete = function(id) {
        alert(id + " deleted!");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="delete(submission.id)">Delete</button>
</div>
```