# AngularJS - Passing nested variable with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression

This answer helped me understand how to bound a variable via ng-click: [How can you pass a bound variable to an ng-click function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647891/how-can-you-pass-a-bound-variable-to-an-ng-click-function)

However, what if the variable that needs to be passed is a nested variable?

For example:

The nested variable: `{{item['id']['attributes']['im:id']}}`

How would this be called inside of ng-click?

```
<a ng-click="open('item['id']['attributes']['im:id']')">
```

Definitely does not work because of the multliple use of the single quote.

Thanks!

__ Edit ___

Attached is the JSFiddle of what I am trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/RUnaE/4/

Basically in $scope.test, the value that I am trying to pass within `ng-click` to the contoller is `{{ item['id']['attributes']['im:id']}}`

Comment: please post your json structure and will be better to show your issue in Fiddle or PLunker, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll get a Plnker up ASAP for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I believe this is the correct solution to the question I asked above: Here is a JSFiddle for future reference: http://jsfiddle.net/RUnaE/6/

```
ng-click="open(item.id.attributes['im:id'])"
```

The non-proper variable is placed within enclosing brackets.

Hope this will help future searchers.