# AngularJS ng-click not working with Laravel as expected

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am working with Angular within Laravel and when you see the "<%" & "%>" they represent the same thing in Angular as "{{" & "}}" because I am using blade with Laravel, I use the notation to differentiate between the two.

OK, with that out of the way. Here is the code and only the hard coded ng-click - ng-click="getPgn(1)" - is the only one working:

```
    <ul class="pagination" ng-model="$scope.songData">
        <li><a href="javascript://" ng-click="getPgn(1)"> &lt;&lt; </a> </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="javascript://" ng-click="getPgn(<% songData.current_page %>)"><% songData.current_page %></a> </li>
        <li><a href="javascript://" ng-click="getPgn(<% songData.current_page+1 %>)" ng-if="(songData.current_page+1) < (songData.last_page)"><% songData.current_page+1 %></a> </li>
        <li><a href="javascript://" ng-click="getPgn(<% songData.current_page+2 %>)" ng-if="(songData.current_page+2) < (songData.last_page)"><% songData.current_page+2 %></a> </li>
        <li><a href="javascript://" ng-click="getPgn(<% songData.current_page+3 %>)" ng-if="(songData.current_page+3) < (songData.last_page)"><% songData.current_page+3 %></a> </li>
        <li><a href="javascript://" ng-click="getPgn(<% songData.current_page+4 %>)" ng-if="(songData.current_page+4) < (songData.last_page)"><% songData.current_page+4 %></a> </li>
        <li><a href="javascript://" ng-click="getPgn(<% songData.current_page+5 %>)" ng-if="(songData.current_page+5) < (songData.last_page)"><% songData.current_page+5 %></a> </li>
        <li><a href="javascript://" ng-click="getPgn(<% songData.current_page+6 %>)" ng-if="(songData.current_page+6) < (songData.last_page)"> &gt; </a> </li>
        <li><a href="javascript://" ng-click="getPgn(<% songData.last_page %>)"> &gt;&gt; </a> </li>
    </ul>
```

Within the controller(angular):

```
    $scope.getPgn = function(pageNum) {
        console.log("pageNum: "+pageNum);
        Song.getPage(pageNum)
            .success(function (data) {
                location.href = "/?page=" + pageNum;
                $scope.songData = data;
                mSongs = data;
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
    }
```

Within the services(angular):

```
        getPage : function(id) {
            return $http.get('/api/songs/?page=' + id);
        }
```

So why does the first one, which is hard coded work and the remainder do not?

When I look in Firebug or any inspector, then it shows the same thing getPgn(2),getPgn(3),etc...

Why?

Comment: In console, do they get called when you click them? You wrote `console.log..`. Does it print?

Comment: Only the first one - getPgn(1) - If I place this in the uri - http://localhost:8000/api/songs/?page=1 or any number it returns the json just fine

Comment: Yeah server would work fine, it's a client issue. Any errors in console?

Comment: No errors - as if I didn't even click

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, that's why I'm asking :) If it's anything like Razor you can try to wrap the `<% %>` with single quotes.

Comment: Oh I've just noticed. `ng-model="$scope.songData"` should be `ng-model="songData"`. You don't use `$scope` when in view.

Comment: I have tried ng-click="getPgn('<% songData.current_page+1 %>')" but once more, only the first getPgn('1') works. It is as if only that one is clickable and that is why I think maybe it has to do with ng-if, maybe?

Comment: If you see the elements then it's not an `ng-if` issue. Anyway to construct a js fiddle of this?

Comment: I just tried it with just songData and same thing only the first hard coded one gets in response. Do you think it is because class="ng-binding" on the other ones but not on the first hard coded one?

Comment: The solution is the ng-click cannot accept curly braces, when passing a parameter(s). The "<%" & "%>" act as "{{" & "}}" - this works -  getPgn(songData.current_page). Found the solution on another stackoverflow post, but found it via google search - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647891/how-can-you-pass-a-bound-variable-to-an-ng-click-function