# Why ng-click is unable to send function parameter which is embraced with curly {{ }} brackets?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to send a path by calling a function, by sending the path as function parameter.

However my controller code:

```
$scope.go = function(path){
    alert(path); //show the path comes in as parameter
    $location.path( path );
  }
```

My view code (.html)

```
<button ng-click="go('/hotellist/{{topHeading}}?tab=packages')" ></button>
```

I have checked `{{topheading}}` it gets the value of  `$scope.topheading`correctly, but when i am sending this using `ng-click`it is getting no value at all! The **alert** is just saying `'/hotelist/?tab=packages'` .

Any Idea? why this is happening?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647891/how-can-you-pass-a-bound-variable-to-an-ng-click-function

Comment: You ask Why, this may help you understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$location) {
$scope.topHeading = "test";  
$scope.go = function(path){
    console.log(path);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


 <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <button ng-click="go('/hotellist/'+topHeading+'?tab=packages')">GO</button>
    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are going to be doing this a lot in your app, you should look at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) it will help you immensely.

Second, have you tried having a method return the url:

```
<button ng-click="vm.packagesPath()"></button>
```

And in your controller:

```
packagesPath() {
  return `/hotellist/${$scope.topHeading}?tab=packages`;
}
```

Your topHeading would obviously be on the scope. Try that, see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<button ng-click="go('/hotellist/' + topHeading + '?tab=packages')" ></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

On button click try this :

```
<button ng-click="go('/hotellist/'+topHeading+'?tab=packages')" ></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not send scope variables like this. Use only `topheading` in ng-click.

Comment: i did this but not working it is sending "/hotellist/topHeading?tab=packages" directly as a parameter, which is a wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use brackets inside `ngClick`. The correct way is:

```
<button ng-click="go('/hotellist/topHeading?tab=packages')"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because there is no value in that scope variable. I tried this code and it worked.

First I have set the Scope variable value with another function using ng-init. Then I used that value in ng-click.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="SetScopeVariable()">
Name: <input type="button" ng-click="getPath('/hotellist/'+topHeading+'?tab=packages')">
```

**Script**

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.SetScopeVariable=function(){
$scope.topHeading='123';
}
$scope.getPath=function(path){
alert(path);
}
});
```

Comment: +topHeading+ , these + and ' signs in the url string was crucial.